# Codificar antes ou depois do super

Tags: java, android, orientação-a-objetos

Quando **sobrescrevemos** um método, sempre vem o `super` da classe pai, mas na hora de codificar o certo a se fazer seria antes ou depois dele?

**No exemplo abaixo o certo seria esse:**

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Aqui", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

**Ou esse:**

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Aqui", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    super.onStart();
}
```

**Ou tanto faz?**

Qual é a melhor prática? Ou vai depender de cada caso, por exemplo se precisarmos que a classe pai faça seu trabalho primeiro.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No seu caso específico, é bom você primeiro avisar a funcionalidade da classe pai do evento *start*, e portanto o `super.onStart();` estaria no início.

No entanto cada caso é um caso. Há casos, onde o melhor é colocar no começo. Em outros casos é melhor colocar no final. Há casos ainda onde pode aparecer no meio, aparecer mais de uma vez, aparecer dentro de um `if`, e outros casos. Isso depende muito da funcionalidade oferecida pela classe pai que você quer usar. Há ainda que se considerar se a chamada ao método da classe pai tem que estar dentro de um `try-catch` e como lidar com exceções lançadas pelo método da classe pai.

Aqui vai um exemplo bem simples, mas que mostra que essa decisão pode ser complexa:

```
public class Pessoa {
    public void pegarObjetoNoQuarto(Objeto a, Quarto b) throws NaoAchouException {
        // ...
    }

    public void acenderLuz(Quarto x) { /* ... */ }

    public void apagarLuz(Quarto x) { /* ... */ }
}
```

```
public class PessoaCuidadosa extends Pessoa {
    @Override
    public void pegarObjetoNoQuarto(Objeto a, Quarto b) throws NaoAchouException {
        acenderLuz(b);
        try {
            super.pegarObjetoNoQuarto(a, b);
        } finally {
            apagarLuz(b);
        }
    }
}
```

No entanto, hoje em dia a herança de classes já é considerada uma má prática de programação, vez que promove um forte acoplamento entre classes. O melhor é você não depender de herança se possível. É verdade que há casos onde você é forçado a usar herança, especialmente quando se usa algum *framework* ou ferramenta que foi projetado para ser usado dessa forma, mas excetuando-se esses casos, evite o uso de herança. Eliminando-se a herança, elimina-se também a questão de ter que decidir onde chamar o `super`.

Comment: Muito obrigado, excelente explicação